# libcurl download file size exceed buffer size

Tags: c, libcurl

I have a question regarding this code at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html

In the call back function

```
static size_t my_fwrite(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  struct FtpFile *out=(struct FtpFile *)stream;
  if(out && !out->stream) {
    /* open file for writing */ 
    out->stream=fopen(out->filename, "wb");
    if(!out->stream)
      return -1; /* failure, can't open file to write */ 
  }
  return fwrite(buffer, size, nmemb, out->stream);
}
```

What if the file size exceed the buffer size? I think the function will not be called iteratively since it overwrites the file everytime. Is there a work-around of it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What overwrites what file?

Comment: @melpomene Copying from the comment below: my question is given that single call of the callback function is not able to complete loading the whole file, does the curl continue running (calling the callback function multiple times) to complete the file downloading? Sorry if ask a very stupid question. I don't quite understand the whole curl process very well. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used curl but I'm pretty sure it will call the callback function repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From curl [*documentation*](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) :

> The callback function will be passed as much data as possible in all
>   invokes, but you must not make any assumptions. It may be one byte, it
>   may be thousands. ***The maximum amount of body data that will be passed
>   to the write callback is defined in the curl.h header file:
>   CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE (the usual default is 16K)***. If CURLOPT_HEADER is
>   enabled, which makes header data get passed to the write callback, you
>   can get up to CURL_MAX_HTTP_HEADER bytes of header data passed into
>   it. This usually means 100K.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my question is given that single call of the callback function is not able to complete loading the whole file, does the curl continue running (calling the callback function multiple times) to complete the file downloading?  Sorry if ask a very stupid question. I don't quite understand the whole curl process very well.

Comment: The _buffer_ is the delivered data to callback function, it will receives chunks

Comment: If you want to write to a memory, refer [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) to make it more clear